#highcharts. Need to show stacked bar charts to visualize result code by partners for Sales API’s data. But its not working while implementing it
We want to show stacked bar charts to visualize result code by partners for our  Sales API’s data. But while visualizing in high charts the data that we are extracting from Azure AIPs (Azure SQL / Azure Synapse Analytics Database ) are currently not displaying on the same horizontal bar charts. Please look into this issue and help me with this so we can visualize it properly.
Reference link:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/bar-stacked
Below are the reports definitions for Sales bar chart that we have injected in our Canvas Insights Application:
{
    "category": "Sales",
    "data": [
        {
            "property": "xAxis.categories",
            "queryDefinition": "Select partner From [dm_na_sit_csinsight].[vw_sales_all_material_test_final] Where TransactionDate >= cast('@startDate' as Date) And TransactionDate <= cast('@endDate' as Date) GROUP BY partner;"
        },
        {
            "property": "series[0].data",
            "queryDefinition": "Select count(partner), count(resultcode)from [dm_na_sit_csinsight].[vw_sales_all_material_test_final] where TransactionDate >= cast('@startDate'as Date) and TransactionDate <= cast('@endDate' as Date) GROUP BY partner;"
        }
    ],
    "name": "responsecodeByPartner",
    "options": {
        "chart": {
            "renderTo": "container",
            "type": "bar"
        },
        "title": {
            "text": "The Result Code by Partner",
            "align": "center"
        },
        "plotOptions": {
            "stacking": "normal",
            "series": {
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
        },
        "xAxis": {
            "type": "datetime",
            "labels": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "title": {
                "text": "Partners"
            }
        },
        "yAxis": {
            "min": 100,
            "tickInterval": 1000,
            "title": {
                "text": "Total Count of Partner"
            }
        },
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Partner"
            }
        ]
    },
},


Hi @Ramanuj Pandey, Could you check the result of your queryDefinition in JS and provide a sample of it here?
